# strange behavior in for statement (swift)

Tags: swift, for-loop, compiler-warnings

I'm developing an application using swift. Today I updated my Xcode (version 7) and I get a lot of same warning.

the problem is in the for-statement

here's the code:

```
    let dict:NSDictionary
    for dict in offers_to_show{

        //do something
    }
```

- offers_to_show is a NSArray and it contains only NSDictionary

I get "Immutable value 'dict' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it"
How can I solve it?

thank for your support,
Mirco

Answer (score 0):

When you name the binding variable `dict`, you're shadowing the local variable `dict` (which you never use). Swift is telling you to remove the unnecessary (and confusing) `let dict:NSDictionary` line.

Comment: ok, so i't very easy. i can delete first variable, and nothing happens to code right?

Comment: Correct. The first 'let' line is just creating a variable that you think you're using, but aren't. Swift's for-in syntax isn't like C's for syntax where the iterating variable has to exist. In a Swift for-in, the name you give after the "for" is the name that will be used for each element. It's not really a "variable".

Answer (score 0):

> I get "Immutable value 'dict' was never used

That's because there are two `dict` variables: the constant one that you create on the first line, and the one in the `for` loop. As described in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html), the index variable in a `for-in` loop is declared implicitly -- you don't need to declare it yourself as you're trying to do with the `let dict...` line, and again, that's actually a separate variable in a different scope.

You're not using the first one, so the compiler points this out. Nothing changed in your code -- the compiler just got better at finding unused code.